# Get all post from users which my user follow

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I would like to get all posts of all users which my user follow.

My User model looks like

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from apps.friend_request.models import FriendRequest


# Save avatar to user specific directory in media files
def user_avatar_directory(instance, filename):
    return f'{instance.username}/avatar/{filename}'


class User(AbstractUser):
    # Field that is used as the unique identifier
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    # Fields that are required when using createsuperuser (username_field and password fields are required by default)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    # Fields that shall be treated as public and can be exposed to all logged-in users
    PUBLIC_FIELDS = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country')

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    about = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_avatar_directory, blank=True, null=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(to='self', symmetrical=False, related_name='followees', blank=True)
```

my post model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        #to=User,
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts',
        #null=True
    )
    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        blank=False
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True
    )
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(
         #to=User,
         to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
         related_name='liked_posts',
         blank=True
    )

    # TODO
    # comments = Set('Comment')

    # TODO sharing not yet clear what it is about
    # shared = Optional('Post', reverse='sharing')
    # sharing = Set('Post', reverse='shared')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID: {self.pk}: {self.content} '

class Post_Pic(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True
    )
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts',
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='post_pic'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID: {self.pk} Post: {self.post_id} File: {self.image.name}'
```

my views.py

```
class MyFollowersPosts(ListView):
    """
    Get all followers
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FollowesSerilizer

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = []
        for user in self.request.user.followers.all():
            for post in Post.objects.filter(author=user.followed):
                posts.append(post)

        return posts
```

Problem is that I am always getting this error and I can´t find out where is problem

*AttributeError at /backend/api/social/posts/following/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'followers'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/api/social/posts/following/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:

'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'followers'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py, line 241, in inner
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.1
Python Path:

['C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\day-5-django-motion-assignment',
'C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend\DLLs',
'C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend\lib',
'C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend',
'C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\motion-backend\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 04 Jan 2021 13:53:46 +0000*

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_queryset` should return a `QuerySet`, not a list. You furthermore do *not* need to obtain items with a loop, you can query with:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class MyFollowersPosts(ListView):
    # …
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author__followees=self.request.user)
```

Furthermore the user should be *logged in*.  You do this with the `IsAuthenticated` permission class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
user = request.user    
followings_posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in = user.followees.all())
```